# Why is Math an object while String is a function?

Tags: javascript

The following is the screenshot of my Chrome javascript console:

[image]

Why `Math` is considered as an object while `String`, `Boolean` and `Window` are all considered as functions?

Comment: Were you expecting `Math` to be a function? It's not like you can call `Math(args)` and have it do math.

Comment: Just type `Math` in console. You will see it as `Object`. Type the others in console. You will see them as `functions`

Comment: The thing that is interesting to me is that it's an empty object in node

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String` and `Boolean` are constructor functions used for explicitly creating objects of that type and can be used as:

```
var s = new String("hello");
var t = new Boolean(true);
```

It generally isn't necessary to use these constructors directly like this, but they are there if, for some reason, you need a full string or boolean object rather than a primitive.

---

`Math` is an object used as a namespace that works as a container to hold a bunch of math functions such as `Math.min()`, `Math.max()`, `Math.random()`, etc...  It is not a constructor and does not create other objects by itself.  You can see a detailed description of the `Math` object [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math).

From that description:

> Math is a built-in object that has properties and methods for
>   mathematical constants and functions. Not a function object.
>
> Unlike the other global objects, Math is not a constructor. All
>   properties and methods of Math are static. You refer to the constant
>   pi as Math.PI and you call the sine function as Math.sin(x), where x
>   is the method's argument. Constants are defined with the full
>   precision of real numbers in JavaScript.

They are different things for different purposes.

---

`Window` is a bit of a different beast.  It's likely related to the host object `window`, but though it reports as a `function` with native code behind it, the Chrome browser won't let you call it either as a function or as a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In simple example, you can see different between Math object and String function
`Math` is object, that has namespace functions

```
var Math = {
  min : function(arg){
     //code here
   }
}
```

String is function and define as

```
function String(){

}
String.prototype.match = function(){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`String` is a `function` because you need to create multiple instances of that `function` with `new`. If string was a container then it wasn't going to be a `function`.

```
var str = new String();
```

Math is an object because you need a single declaration of that object that carries utility methods like `Math.random`.

```
// You cannot do that, so error.
var math = new Math();
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math

> Summary Math is a built-in object that has properties and methods for
>   mathematical constants and functions. Not a function object.
>
> Description Unlike the other global objects, Math is not a
>   constructor. All properties and methods of Math are static. You refer
>   to the constant pi as Math.PI and you call the sine function as
>   Math.sin(x), where x is the method's argument. Constants are defined
>   with the full precision of real numbers in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Math is a global object in JavaScript with no constructor. All methods and properties are static and you can not create a new object by using `new` keyword. That's why you are seeing it as an object.